# Does motion with constant proper acceleration, in a flat region, necessarily mean straight hyperbolic motion?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, terminology

Is motion of a participant with constant proper acceleration, in a flat region, necessarily straight, hyperbolic motion (with respect to members of any inertial system, in that region)?

Or is for instance a participant who is moving at constant speed along a circular trajectory wrt. members of an inertial system said to have moved with constant proper acceleration, too?

Answer (score 0):

For motion along a circular trajectory the acceleration changes its direction, and is not constant.

Comment: Jerrold Franklin: "_For motion along a circular trajectory the acceleration changes its direction_" -- That's certainly true of the acceleration vector evaluated in reference to any inertal system (since the members of an inertial system, in a flat region, are not rotating). But if we're considering **proper acceleration**, i.e. the acceleration of the participant under consideration, at some instant, wrt. the corresponding instantaneously comoving inertial system then ... the notion of "(constancy, or change of) _direction_" may be more difficult; perhaps just a matter of convention.